# Matrix vector multiple acceleration with openmp or pthread

Tags: matrix, vector, pthreads, openmp

given three array as follows, I want to get a dot production by kernel X input' -> output), I want to accelerate this function with OpenMP or pthread, but there are no speedup or even worse,  anyone has better methods?

```
  output[outN];
  input[inN];
  kernel[outN*inN];

  for(int i=0;i<outN;i++)
  {
          float sum = bias[i];
          for(int j=0;j<inN;j++)
                   sum += input[j]*kernel[i*inN+j];

          output[i] = sum;
 }
```

Comment: Better method: use a library optimized for this operation such as (the now free) MKL,or any of the many freely available  BLAS libraries. (Google is your friend)

Comment: Matrix*vector is memory bandwidth bound and does not scale with multiple threads and SIMD lanes. You may see some speed up using two threads with scalar operations because it's difficult to obtain the peak memory bandwidth but other than that you can't expect much more on a system with a single memory controller. On a multisocket system it will scale with the number of memory controllers. But in any case is the best answer is to not do long dot products. Do them in blocks that fit in the cache along with other operations.